# Java Linked regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have to parse the following sample output. The requirements are there should be no text after `Fabric management FPC state:` i.e. it should be empty `\s`. The next part is a bit tricky and I am stuck there. So each `FPC` has one or more `PFE` and each `FPE` has one or more `SIB`. There are four possible states for each `SIB`. They are `Plane Enabled, Link Error, Desination Error and Plane Disabled`. I am supposed to parse this using regex and keep track of the state for each `FPC, PFE and SIB`. I am not sure how to have a `'linked'` groups in regex.

```
Fabric management FPC state:                                  
FPC #0
  PFE #0
    SIB #0 
            Plane enabled
    SIB #1 
            Link Error        
  PFE #1
    SIB #0 
            Destination Error
    SIB #1 
            Plane Disabled
    SIB #2 
            Plane enabled       
FPC #1
  PFE #1
    SIB #0 
            Plane enabled
```

So far what I have is

```
public void parseFPCS(String commandOutput) {
        regex = "FPC state:(\\s*)(FPC\\s*#?\\d+)\\s*(PFE\\s*#\\d+)\\s*(SIB\\s*#\\d+)\\s*(\\w*\\s*\\w*)";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, patternFlag);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(commandOutput);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            String empty = matcher.group(1);
            Boolean isEmpty = empty.trim().isEmpty();
            if(isEmpty) {
                System.out.println("Link Empty");
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
                System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
                System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
                System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
                //Right now I am just printing it out to see the outcome. 
            }

        }

The current outcome is 
    Link Empty
    FPC #0
    PFE #0
    SIB #0
    Plane enabled //This is expected.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of having one huge complex regex, I will prefer to do it in conditional loops with multiple regexes.

Comment: Approaching that way would be easier.